# action sheet hiding the button showing it in scroll view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiactionsheet

I have a UIButton on a scroll view. On clicking that button action sheet appears. But the button gets hide behind the sheet. I want button to be scrolled up so that it remains visible above action sheet.
Please help

```
        - (IBAction)foodInstructionOrPrescriptionInformationButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        tagForPicker = sender.tag;
      [self presentPicker:sender];
    }
    - (void)presentPicker:(UIButton*)element
    {


        actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0)];
        picker.tag = tagForPicker;
        picker.dataSource = self;
        picker.delegate = self;
        [actionSheet addSubview:picker];
        UIToolbar *tools = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 40)];
        tools.barStyle=UIBarStyleDefault;
        [actionSheet addSubview:tools];
        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(btnActionPickerDoneClicked)];
        UIBarButtonItem *CancelButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(btnActionPickerCancelClicked)];
        UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:CancelButton,flexSpace,flexSpace,doneButton,nil];
        [tools setItems:array];



      if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
      {
        [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
        [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 400)];

      }
      else
      {
        [actionSheet showFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 215) inView:self.view animated:YES];
        [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 511)];

      }

    }

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [backgroundScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,1340)];
}
```

Comment: Could you please show us some code?

Comment: Please see now. the button is on a scroll view